# Why does the animation runing time does not get shorter or longer?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

So I have this script and I am trying to make a cube jump to a certain location, and part of that is that I want the cube to play an animation while it moves towards the new Rich Point, I have the following script but for some reason the animation does not get shorter or longer why? What am I doing wrong?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public float jumpMaxDistance;
    public float jumpSpeed;
    private float distance;

    private bool firstFrame = false;
    private Vector3 richPoint;
    public GameObject player;
    private Animation jump;

    void Start () {
        richPoint = transform.position;
        jump = player.GetComponent<Animation> ();

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update (){
        //Moves the player to the next point.
        if (firstFrame == true){
            if (transform.position != richPoint) {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, richPoint, Time.deltaTime * jumpSpeed);


            }//executes if the left click is pressed.
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

            RaycastHit hit;

            //Get Ray from mouse position.
            Ray rayCast = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

            //Raycast and check if any object is hit.
            if (Physics.Raycast (rayCast, out hit, jumpMaxDistance)) 
                {
                //Raycast and check if any object is hit.
                if (hit.collider.CompareTag ("RichPoint"))
                {
                    richPoint = hit.collider.transform.position;
                    //This finds the distance between the player and richPoint.
                    float pBTime;
                    pBTime = distance / jumpSpeed;

                    //This plays the Animation depending on tha distance between transform.position and richPoint.
                    jump ["PlayerJump"].time = pBTime;
                    jump.Play ();

                    firstFrame = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use animation state. Here [example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html).